# How to set urlpatterns between two app in a project in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I'm creating a project which has two apps for now.
the url patterns of the project and two apps are:

*camroid/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('camroidapp.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

*camroidapp/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

*accounts/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register',views.register, name='register'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

*header portion of my index.html page*

*index.html*

```
    <header class="header-section">
        <a href="index.html" class="site-logo">Camroid<!--<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"> --></a>
        <div class="header-controls">
            <button class="nav-switch-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <button class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
        <ul class="main-menu">

            <li><a href="about.html">The Artist</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-1.html">Portfolio 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-2.html">Portfolio 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="accounts/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="accounts/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="search-mobile">
                <button class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

so when i run the server it uses 'http://127.1.1.1:8880/' and
when i click on login it uses 'http://127.1.1.1:8880/accounts/login'
but when i click on register from login page it calls 'http://127.1.1.1:8880/accounts/accounts/register' which is an invalid url

so what can i do so that when i shift from login page to register it calls 'http://127.1.1.1:8880/accounts/register' and when i shift from register to login page it calls 'http://127.1.1.1:8880/accounts/login'

Comment: I think the problem is with your template html file. Can you add your HTML files here which have link to register ?

Comment: @AstikAnand i added its header portion where i'm calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **named urls** in your view like below to make use of **relative urls**.

```
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. You can mark it as selected if that helps.